# Quarkus PanacheEntityBase query with IN

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a customer entity of type PanacheEntityBase. I would like get all customers by ids

I can get it with customer.list("customerId", id) in a loop. I dont think its a good solution. I prefer using IN. Please suggest how to use IN with PanacheEntityBase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with customerEntity.list("customerId IN (?1)", customerIds);

Note: customersids must be a java list (Array did not work)

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution

Option 1: Repository pattern

```
 @ApplicationScoped
 public class MyRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<MyObject, 
 Long> 
 {
  public List<MyObject> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids) {
     return find("FROM MyObject WHERE id IN ?1", ids).list();
 }
 }
```

Option 2 : Active record pattern

```
 MyObject.list("id in ?1", ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyEntity.list("id IN ?1", ids);
```

here, **MyEntity** is an entity class extending PanacheEntityBase. and **ids** is a List.